# The probability of objects of the same class being in a row.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have 8 blocks of three different colors: red, yellow, and blue. Suppose there are 4 red ones, 3 yellow ones, and 1 blue one. If I randomly line them up, what is the probability that there will be 4 red ones in a row? 3 red ones? 2?

I tried the following:

- 4 red in a row: $\left(4! \cdot {4\choose 4} \cdot 5\right)/8! = 0.30\%$
- 3 red in a row: $\left(3! \cdot {4\choose 3} \cdot 6\right)/8! = 0.36\%$
- 2 red in a row: $\left(2! \cdot {4\choose 2} \cdot 7\right)/8! = 0.21\%$

My reasoning was as follows. In the 4 red in a row case, for example, there are:

- $4!$ ways to order the group of 4 red blocks in a row
- ${4\choose 4}$ ways of choosing 4 red blocks from 4 red blocks (which is trivial in this case but follows the general form)
- $5$ possible positions of 4 consecutive blocks in a group of 8
- $8!$ total possible block orderings

But the probability of 2 red in a row should certainly *not* be greater than the probability of 3 red in a row, so I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone know how to handle this problem?

The general version would be something like: Suppose there are $n$ objects of $m$ different classes. If these objects are randomly ordered, what is the probability of $k$ objects of the same class being in a row?

Comment: The $m$ different classes don't enter into it. You effectively have only $2$ different classes -- objects that you want to see in a row, and other objects. (Unless by "$k$ objects of the same class" you mean any class -- in that case you should clarify that, since in the first paragraph you were only interested in one particular class.)

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the tip, I'll add some more context and show effort in my edits. I'm new here, so I'm getting used to the norms

Comment: For 2 reds in a row, do you mean *only one case of exactly 2 reds in a row* ?

Comment: @trueblueanil No, I mean any ordering that has 2 reds in a row. (So it could have more reds in a row, too.)